# How to compile all CPP file without building the whole project in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++

Is it possible that I can just compile all CPP files under a project and without linking etc. the project?

Comment: Click the first .cpp file in the Solution Explorer window.  Hold down the Shift key and select the last one.  Right-click, Compile.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to do this is by specify the [`/c` switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8we9bhf4.aspx) when you compile the code. Unfortunately, this option is not available from within the Visual Studio development environment, so you'll need to build your code on the command line by calling `cl.exe` directly. To make things easy on yourself, use the Visual Studio Command Prompt to do so.

Not sure if it's possible to get MSBuild to do this, the documentation is unclear whether the limitation is Visual Studio itself or if it's a limitation of MSBuild. I haven't actually tried for myself.

Alternatively, you can build individual source files from within the IDE by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> (at least, assuming the default C++ development settings). If that fails, it's also available as the "Compile" option located in the "Build" menu.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this will do what you need, but may be worth a try: create a project for an executable (rather than a library) and include all cpp files in it. Add a `main()` function that just returns zero. Set the C++ optimisation option to 'optimise references' (`/OPT:REF`). This *may* just compile all the cpp files but effectively ignore them during the link stage since none of them are referenced by the application.

You don't say why you need to do this - is it because linking takes a huge amount of time?